# Managed and save google apps script projects from spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have developed few scripts in a given project attached to a spreadsheet (ie that I first created my spreadsheet, and then created the project with the menu Tools>Script editor).

Now my question is:

- how can I save that project so that it can be used on other spreadsheets?
- how do I select in a given spreadsheet which script project I want to use?

From [this Google documentation page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) I can't see any solution.

Answer (score 0):

To have a script that's not bound to any document, look into making a [standalone script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone).

If you want to use a script in multiple documents, you'll need to publish it as a [library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries).

Comment: yes I did understand that point, but what if I first created the project from a spreadsheet ? is there any other option that just copy/paste each `.gs` into a new project ?

Comment: @clemla You don't need a stand alone script to make a library. You could use the script tied to your spreadsheet by saving it as explained in the link. Then if you want to use that saved library elsewhere--like another spreadsheet--you include that library in that spreadsheet's attached script file.